# glBufferData second arg is GLsizeiptr not GLsizei, why?

Tags: opengl

Basically that's it, why does glBufferData take a pointer instead of an int? This arg is supposed to be the size of the buffer object, so why not GLsizei?

OpenGL doc on glBufferData https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferData.xhtml

Comment: It's not a pointer.  It's an integral type the same size as a pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: This is an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @datenwolf: No, I didn't have an explanation for why this size integer is preferred over that one.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Because OpenGL GLsizei is 32 bits. To accommodate for systems with larger address spaces a new type had to be introduced, that matches the pointer size in such situations.

Comment: @datenwolf: That was my guess, but I don't have any evidence to support it.  Are there some specs or extension specs dealing with buffers > 4GB (or > 2GB if signed) ?  I think a good answer should reference such specs.

Comment: Considering the Direct State Access version of the function still uses `GLsizei` I don't think that's the reason. They promoted the DSA (`named...`) stuff into core recently, and that part of the API uses a typedef that would limit the address space to 32-bit. If this were a real concern, I don't think the DSA version would have been promoted (at least not without some change). Either that or DSA was really sloppily promoted, I have noticed some other weird things with the `Named...` functions for various other parts of the GL API.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The OpenGL specs clearly define GLsizei to be 32 bits and GLsizeiptr to be a "nonnegative integer with a system specific size". The first occurance of GLsizeiptr is the GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension specification (then in the form of GLsizeiptrARB).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman or it slipped through the cracks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When vertex buffer objects were [introduced via the OpenGL extension mechanism](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt), a new type `GLsizeiptrARB` was created and the following rationale was provided:

> *What type should <offset> and <size> arguments use?*
>
> RESOLVED: We define new types that will work well on 64-bit
>           systems, analogous to C's "intptr_t".  The new type "GLintptrARB"
>           should be used in place of GLint whenever it is expected that
>           values might exceed 2 billion.  **The new type "GLsizeiptrARB"
>           should be used in place of GLsizei whenever it is expected
>           that counts might exceed 2 billion.**  Both types are defined as
>           signed integers large enough to contain any pointer value.  As a
>           result, they naturally scale to larger numbers of bits on systems
>           with 64-bit or even larger pointers.
>
> The offsets introduced in this extension are typed GLintptrARB,
>           consistent with other GL parameters that must be non-negative,
>           but are arithmetic in nature (not uint), and are not sizes; for
>           example, the xoffset argument to TexSubImage*D is of type GLint.
>           Buffer sizes are typed GLsizeiptrARB.
>
> The idea of making these types unsigned was considered, but was
>           ultimately rejected on the grounds that supporting buffers larger
>           than 2 GB was not deemed important on 32-bit systems.

When this extension was accepted into core OpenGL, the extension-compliant type `GLsizeiptrARB` for the type got a standardized name `GLsizeiptr` which you see in the function signature today.

Comment: It's so ridiculous these types are signed.