# Why does glMapNamedBufferRange() use GLsizei for length?

Tags: opengl, mapping, buffer

While I seeing OpenGL specification, I noticed something weird.

Here are prototypes for glMapBufferRange() and glMapNamedBufferRange():

```
void *glMapBufferRange( GLenum target,
    GLintptr offset,
    GLsizeiptr length,
    GLbitfield access);

void *glMapNamedBufferRange(    GLuint buffer,
    GLintptr offset,
    GLsizei length,
    GLbitfield access);
```

For length parameter, glMapNamedBufferRange() uses GLsizei type which is 32bit integer while glMapBufferRange() uses GLsizeiptr whose size is >= sizeof(void*).

From the specification, it's not possible to map a very long range of buffer using glMapNamedBufferRange() because GLsizei is only 32bit integer.

On the other hand glMapbufferRange() can map all range of addresses in 64bit platform.

<s>Why does only glMapNamedBufferRange() have such limitation even though its purpose is very similar with glNamedBufferRange()?</s>

edit:

I found similar cases. In fact, lots of named buffer counter parts uses GLsizei when non named version uses GLsizeptr.

Why do named version buffer functions have such limitations?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758129/glbufferdata-second-arg-is-glsizeiptr-not-glsizei-why)

Comment: @Ripi2: Not a duplicate. The question you linked to asks exactly the opposite.

Comment: @BDL I agree. I was looking more at the answer, where you can see an explanation of the same kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of the specification are you looking at? The [OpenGL specification version 4.6 (pdf)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) (and the [associated `gl.xml` file](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry/blob/master/xml/gl.xml?raw=true)) clearly says that `glMapNamedBufferRange` takes a `GLsizeiptr`.

You're probably looking at [the man pages](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages/blob/master/gl4/glMapBufferRange.xml), which can sometimes have errors [like this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages/issues/39). Always check the actual specification first if you see something odd like this.

Comment: Here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml I noticed this page does not mention OpenGL 4.6, by the way.

Comment: @xylosper: As I pointed out, that's *not* the "OpenGL specification".

Comment: Thank you. I double-checked 4.5 and 4.6 specs and confirmed that you're right. It's very annoying thing that such consistent errors exist in Khronos reference page though. Thanks again.